# How can I send complex JavaScript object to ASP.net WebMethod?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying send my client-side custom object (JavaScript) to ASP.net Web Method. I use jQuery Ajax command to perform this operation.

There a example of my object:

```
function Customer() {
    this.Name = "";
    this.Surname = "";

    this.Addresses = new Array();
}
```

I load data with this method:

```
function buildCurrentCustomer() {
    var currentCustomer = new Customer();

    /** General Info **/
    currentCustomer.Name = $("#Name").val();
    currentCustomer.Surname = $("#Surname").val();

    currentCustomer.Addresses = new Array();
    currentCustomer.Addresses["HOME"] = $("#adHome").val();
    currentCustomer.Addresses["OFFICE"] = $("#adOffice").val();

    return currentCustomer;
}
```

And finally I send data with this code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../_layouts/CustomerManager/MasterPage.aspx/SetCustomer",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{customer: " + JSON.stringify(currentCustomer) + "}",
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {

        },
        error: function (ex) {
            WriteToConsole(ex.responseText);
        }
    });
```

My server-side methods is like that:

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool SetCustomer(CustomerModel Customer)
{
    //My code...
}
```

and my CustomerModel class is like that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Common.Model.JavaScriptModel
{
    public class CustomerModel
    {
        /** General Info **/
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string Surname {get;set;}

        public Dictionary<string, string> Addresses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I execute Ajax Call server-side method doesn't execute. If I change signature of server-side method in:

```
public static bool SetCustomer(List<CustomerModel> Customer)
```

SetCustomer method is executed but the List is empty.

Why have I this problem? Where can I find documentation about this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, if you use the data like this

```
data: "{customer: " + JSON.stringify(currentCustomer) + "}",
```

on the code behind, you need to take the same parameter `customer` and not `Customer`, so this

```
public static bool SetCustomer(CustomerModel Customer) { ... }
```

needs to be changed to

```
public static bool SetCustomer(CustomerModel customer) { ... }
```

second, your `Customer` object in the `javascript` is like this if translated to `asp.net`

```
string Name;
string Surname;
List<string> Addresses;
```

but your `class` in the code behind for `Addresses` is using

```
Dictionary<string, string>
```

thus causing your `data` from client side can't be parsed in the server side and return an error to the client side, so you need to change your `Addresses` class to

```
public List<string> Addresses { get; set; }
```

and lastly, your code inside `buildCurrentCustomer` for the `Addresses` is being set like this

```
currentCustomer.Addresses = new Array();
currentCustomer.Addresses["HOME"] = $("#adHome").val();
currentCustomer.Addresses["OFFICE"] = $("#adOffice").val();
```

this will never add a value to `Addresses` since it's type is an `array`, but you set the value to it as if it was an `object`, so if you want to stick to use an `array`, you need to change it to

```
currentCustomer.Addresses = new Array();
currentCustomer.Addresses.push($("#adHome").val());
currentCustomer.Addresses.push($("#adOffice").val());
```

### *Note:

use this if you want to use the `Addresses` as an array, but if you need the `Addresses` to be an `object` that contains `HOME` and `OFFICE`, I'll Edit the answer

### Edit:

perhaps you can use a javascript object like this

```
currentCustomer.Addresses = {};
currentCustomer.Addresses["Home"] = $("#adHome").val();
currentCustomer.Addresses["Office"] = $("#adOffice").val();
```

to make the equivalent for `Dictionary<string,string>` but if it didn't work you could change your `Addresses` to class too like this

```
public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

and add class `Address`

```
public class Address
{
    public string Home {get;set;}
    public string Office {get;set;}
}
```

I myself never used a `Dictionary` myself, so I don't know if it's the same

Comment: Hi Kyojimaru. Thanks for your answer. About Addresses array I would something like Dictionary in C#. Exists in JavaScript?

Comment: @ilMattion, updated the answer of how to do it with an `object` not sure though if it can be used for `Dictionary<string,string>` or not

Comment: Hi Kyojimaru. Your edited answer help me to resolve my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your source code like this..

AJAX-

```
data:  JSON.stringify({'customer':currentCustomer});
```

ASP.net Web Method-

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static bool SetCustomer(object customer)
    {
        CustomerModel CM = new CustomerModel();
        _Serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        _StringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        _Serializer.Serialize(customer, _StringBuilder);
        CM = _Serializer.Deserialize<CustomerModel>(_StringBuilder.ToString());
    }
```

**Note that you have to initialize  _Serializer  and the _StringBuilder properties at the top of the page as global variables...**

```
    public static JavaScriptSerializer _Serializer;
    public static StringBuilder _StringBuilder;
```